# What's the meaning of 'sourceSets.all*'

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm new to gradle & groovy, and I don't know the exact meaning of such a statement:

```
sourceSets.all*.java
```

Is it a valid groovy expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Groovy GPath expression. `*.` calls a property or method (`java` in this case) on every element in a collection (`sourceSets.all` in this case), and returns a collection of the results. In this case it will give you a collection of all Java `SourceDirectorySet`s. In the case of reading a property (like here), the `*` can even be omitted.